# Universal code that disables buttons onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a next issue:

My application contains many buttons that make async requests to the server, currently if user is fast enough to click button more than one time - same request gets executed twice or more and data on the server gets duplicated.
**Is there a way to disable clicked button, until the request is executed?**

Someone suggested this solution:

```
$("input[type='button']")
        .each(function () {
            var el = $(this);
            var onclickFunction = el.attr('onclick'), alreadyChecked = el.attr('clickHandler');

            if (typeof onclickFunction != 'undefined' && typeof alreadyChecked == 'undefined')
            {
                el.removeAttr("onclick");
                el.removeAttr("onclickFunction", onclickFunction);
                el.attr('clickHandler', 'true');
                el.on('click', function()
                {
                    el.attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $.when(eval(onclickFunction)).then(function () { el.removeAttr('disabled'); })

                })

            }
        });
```

But if i understood correctly, this code runs only once. So if my application contains many views, this code should be executed on each view load.

Is there any more apropriate solution?

Comment: I am not sure why you had to use eval.Why can't you define the function is JS instead of reading the function source as a string and doing an [eval](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) on it.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways.

1) Use a flag(let's call it requestInProgress) in the page scope that is turned on once the request is made. Once the request is completed, turn off the flag.

2) Disable the button once the button is request is getting processing so as to prevent user from hitting it a second time. Enable the button once the request processing is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.one()`

```
function handleClick(e) {
  // not necessary, though notifies user button is disabled
  $(this).attr("disabled", true); 
  // do ajax stuff
  $.ajax().then(function() {
    $(e.target).removeAttr("disabled")
    // reattach `click` when ajax completes
    .one("click", handleClick)
  })
}

$("input[type='button']").one("click", handleClick)
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, your solution also makes me to rewrite all the existing button click handlers?

Comment: @Cheese _"If i'm not mistaken, your solution also makes me to rewrite all the existing button click handlers?"_ Not certain what you mean? You can define handlers as named functions instead of anonymoys functions, substitute `.one()` for `.on()`, reattach `click` event at `$.ajax()` success or error to call same named function as handler at next click

Comment: in code that i have added i see that i'm wrapping the click handler into a variable:

var onclickFunction = el.attr('onclick');

and then evaluating it.

should i put the same code in your sample where the "/ do ajax stuff" comment is?

Comment: @Cheese What is text of `el.attr('onclick')` / `onclickFunction`? What is purpose of using event attribute `onclick`? Yes, you should be able to define click handler as a named function, including ajax `js` within handler; use `.one("click", clickHandler)`

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is using a CSS `class` to prevent the user from multiple submissions.  This also provides you the flexibility of easily styling the appearance for disabled buttons as well, say for their `color` or `opacity` in your `stylesheet`.

Something like this:

```
function onClickHandler() {
  var myButton = $(this);

  // check to see if it's already disabled
  if (myButton.hasClass('disabled')) {
    // if so, just exit out
    return;
  }

  // add the disabled class
  myButton.addClass('disabled');

  // continue with your processing...
}
```

If browser compatibility is not an issue, you could also check out the [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled) attribute, but I'm personally a bigger fan of using a `class`.